# Variables inside control properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

This code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="<%=Settings.UsernameMaxLength %>" ID="Username"/>
```

Throws a parser error.

Is it possible to set properties in any way similar to this without using the code behind?

Comment: Please try with single quotes `MaxLength='<%=Settings.UsernameMaxLength %>'`

Comment: I suppose, you can do the same thing using code behind in the `page_init` event.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Syntax `<%= some code here %>` cannot be used with server-side controls. You can either go with `<%# some code here %>`, but only in case of data binding, or just set this property in code behind, say on `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Username.MaxLength = Settings.UsernameMaxLength;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, which should set the **MaxLength** value upon rendering :

```
<%
  Username.MaxLength = Settings.UsernameMaxLength;
%>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Username"/>
```

I think (not tried) you can also write :

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="<%#Settings.UsernameMaxLength %>" ID="Username"/>
```

But you would then need to `call Username.DataBind()` somewhere in the codebehind.

Comment: `TextBox` itself cannot be data bound. Second option will work only when `Username` is situated inside some control that can be data bound, like `GridView`.

Comment: @Andrei I just gave a try to second option and it seems to work without any other bindable container control. TextBox does feature a DataBind method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.databind.aspx

Comment: Huh, that is a surprise. Never knew that TextBox now has DataBind method (seems that it is so since ASP.NET 3.5). It also well explains why second option works without wrapping data bound control. Thanks for info!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here, but here goes anyway...

You could build your own `Expression Builder` to handle this case. That would allow you to use syntax like this:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    runat="server" 
    MaxLength="<%$ MySettings: UsernameMaxLength %>"
    ID="Username"/>
```

Note the `$` sign.

To learn how to make you own `Expression Builder`, please go through this old but still relevant [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125044/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022509-1.aspx). Don't let the wall of text scare you off because in the end, making an expression builder is easy. It basically consists of deriving a class from `System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilder` and overriding the `GetCodeExpression` method. Here is a very simple example (some parts of this code was borrowed from the linked tutorial):

```
public class SettingsExpressionBuilder : System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilder
{
    public override System.CodeDom.CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(System.Web.UI.BoundPropertyEntry entry, object parsedData, System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilderContext context)
    {
        // here is where the magic happens that tells the compiler
        // what to do with the expression it found.
        // in this case we return a CodeMethodInvokeExpression that
        // makes the compiler insert a call to our custom method
        // 'GetValueFromKey'
        CodeExpression[] inputParams = new CodeExpression[] {
            new CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Expression.Trim()), 
            new CodeTypeOfExpression(entry.DeclaringType), 
            new CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.PropertyInfo.Name)
        };

        return new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
            new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(
                this.GetType()
            ),
            "GetValueFromKey",
            inputParams
        );
    }
    public static object GetValueFromKey(string key, Type targetType, string propertyName)
    {
        // here is where you take the provided key and find the corresponding value to return.
        // in this trivial sample, the key itself is returned.
        return key;
    }
}
```

In order to use it in your aspx page, you must also register it in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation ...>
            <expressionBuilders>
                <add expressionPrefix="MySettings" type="SettingsExpressionBuilder"/>
            </expressionBuilders>
         </compilation>
     </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is just to show you that it's not difficult. But please review the tutorial I linked to in order to see an example of how to deal with the expected return type from your method depending on the property being assigned etc.